# Finding the matrix to do given transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I was given the following question:

> Find the $3 \times 3$ matrix that produces the described composite $2$D transformation below, using homogeneous coordinates.
> Translate by $(-3,2)$, and then scale the $X$-coordinate by $0.2$ and the $Y-$coordinate by $1.2.$

I have the answer key and don't need to send in an answer, so I'm not simply looking for the solution. I want to know how to solve it so I can solve similar problems.

Can anyone help me out at all?

I would like to be able to solve this kind of problem, but I don't understand the method of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

A translation by $(a,b)$ should transform the point $(x,y,1)$ in homogenous coordinates to the point $(x+a,y+b,1)$. This is the linear transformation described by the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&a\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

So that's the matrix you need to apply to the homogenous coordinates to get a translation by $(a,b)$. And then scaling is the same as in the affine space, just keep the third coordinate constant. So scaling the $x$-coordinate by $c$ and the $y$-coordinate by $d$ is described by the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(c,d,1)$. The rest is just the usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you. You wrote that scaling is the same as in the affine space. Can you explain what that means?

Comment: In the affine plane $\mathbb R^2$, scaling all components of a vector by a given number is done by multiplying the components by that number. In homogenous coordinates (which are usually used to describe the projective plane), this is still the same. The point $(x,y)$ in inhomogenous coordinates is $(x,y,1)$ in homogenous coordinates. So after scaling, $(cx,dy)$ in inhomogenous coordinates is $(cx,dy,1)$ in homogenous coordinates, so you still just multiply the $x$- and $y$-components by their respective scalar, and leave the third homogenous coordinate as is.